# boto SQS NoSuchVersion Error

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-sqs

My problem is best described by the following script:

```
import boto
boto.__version__
# OUT: '2.19.0'
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection
ec2 = EC2Connection(**creds)
regions = ec2.get_all_regions()
from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection
regions[0]
# OUT: RegionInfo:eu-west-1
sqs = SQSConnection(region=regions[0], **creds)
sqs.get_all_queues()
# OUT: Traceback (most recent call last):
# OUT:   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
# OUT:   File "/opt/zenoss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/sqs/connection.py", line 338, in get_all_queues
# OUT:     return self.get_list('ListQueues', params, [('QueueUrl', Queue)])
# OUT:   File "/opt/zenoss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1119, in get_list
# OUT:     raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
# OUT: SQSError: SQSError: 400 Bad Request
# OUT: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# OUT: <Response><Errors><Error><Code>NoSuchVersion</Code><Message>The requested version (2012-11-05) of service AmazonEC2 does not exist</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>1600907e-6780-46f5-b5e6-e647a660abf8</RequestID></Response>
```

I could not find documentation for AWS or boto about meaning of this error, and how to fix it. Is that a bug of boto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the above code is that the `get_all_regions()` call from the EC2 module returns a list of `RegionInfo` objects consisting of a region name and a region endpoint.  But the endpoint is for the EC2 service, not SQS.  So, if you pass that `RegionInfo` into the `SQSConnection` constructor it will end up trying to make SQS requests against an EC2 endpoint which results in the `NoSuchVersion` error.

Here's how I would do this:

```
import boto.sqs

sqs = boto.sqs.connect_to_region('eu-west-1')
sqs.get_all_queues()
```

Similarly, if you need an EC2 connection:

```
import boto.ec2

ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('eu-west-1')
```